# Sufficient condition that the Infimum of an uncountable family of measurable functions is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum, measurable-functions

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space and $(f_r)_{r \in \mathbb{R}}$ be a family of $\mathcal{F}-\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable functions $f_r : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. In general, the pointwise Infimum of an uncountable family is not measurable as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/452773/1055637).

However, one of my homework assignments claims that if for every $\omega \in \Omega$ the function $\varphi_{\omega}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\varphi_{\omega}(r) := f_r(\omega)$ is continuous, then $\inf_{r \in \mathbb{R}}f_r$ is $\mathcal{F}-\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable. I'm struggling to come up with a proof of this though, I can't really see how continuity of the $\varphi_{\omega}$ might come into play here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $\inf_{r \in \mathbb R} f_r(\omega)=\inf_{r \in \mathbb Q} f_r(\omega)$ in this case.

Comment: @geetha290krm Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: It is against rules to seek a detailed answer to a homework problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spelling out geetha290krm's comment; we have (evaluating pointwise)
$$
(\inf_{r\in\Bbb R}f_r)(\omega)
= \inf_{r\in\Bbb R}(f_r(\omega))
= \inf_{r\in\Bbb R}(\varphi_\omega(r))
= \inf_{q\in\Bbb Q}(\varphi_\omega(q))
= \inf_{q\in\Bbb Q}(f_q(\omega))
= (\inf_{q\in\Bbb Q}f_q)(\omega),
$$
so
$$\inf_{r\in\Bbb R}f_r = \inf_{q\in\Bbb Q}f_q.$$

For passing from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb Q$, see [Supremum over real interval equals supremum over rational 'interval' for continuos functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4093005/620957). To finish from the above, see [The Supremum and Infimum of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1456350/620957).

Comment: Please do not solve homework problems .

Comment: @geetha290krm Oh dear, you’re right, I’m sorry. I can’t even delete it now, but the damage is already done anyways I suppose.